# Statements inside of Conditionals (if)

Tags: javascript

Is there a safe way to move the following code? I am working on an open source archived game which was minified and am unfamilar with the syntax

```
if (
      (72 !== event.which && UI.hideHelp(),
      null != c && P(event.which))
){
    // some stuff
}
```

What is actually happening here? If I was to make it more readable, does it become this:

```
if (72 !== event.which){
    UI.hideHelp();
}
if ((null != c && P(event.which))){
    // some stuff
}
```

Or this?

```
if ((null != c && P(event.which))){
    if (72 !== event.which){
        UI.hideHelp();
    }
    // some stuff
}
```

Comment: Is there really nothing inside the `{}` block at the end of the `if` in the original code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance there is! I just wanted to avoid the bloat. I will edit my question!

Comment: Your first refactoring is correct. Comma operator evaluates its left expression, discards it, then evaluates to the value of its right expression.

Comment: Often, it has very low precedence, and is often used in minification.